# compiler dependent null pointer problem in fortran

Tags: fortran, pgi

I'm trying to compile one particular numerical code named NEMO. I'm using PGI compiler and get the following error while I'm trying to run a case.

```
-> report : Performance report : Time spent for XIOS : 4.53964e-05
-> report : Performance report : Time spent in processing events : 0
-> report : Performance report : Ratio : 0%
-> report : Performance report : Time spent for XIOS : 4.54746e-05
-> report : Performance report : Time spent in processing events : 0
-> report : Performance report : Ratio : 0%
0: Null pointer for qrp (/home/user/local/NEMO-4.0/cfgs/MYGYRE/BLD/ppsrc/nemo/diawri.f90: 530)

0: Null pointer for qrp (/home/user/local/NEMO-4.0/cfgs/MYGYRE/BLD/ppsrc/nemo/diawri.f90: 530)

0: Null pointer for qrp (/home/user/local/NEMO-4.0/cfgs/MYGYRE/BLD/ppsrc/nemo/diawri.f90: 530)

0: Null pointer for qrp (/home/user/local/NEMO-4.0/cfgs/MYGYRE/BLD/ppsrc/nemo/diawri.f90: 530)
```

The corresponding code from the diawri.f90 file is as followed

```
530          CALL histwrite( nid_T, "sohefldp", it, qrp           , ndim_hT, ndex_hT )   ! heat flux damping
```

Following is the interface of histwrite

```
  INTERFACE histwrite
!---------------------------------------------------------------------
!- The "histwrite" routines will give the data to the I/O system.
!- It will trigger the operations to be performed,
!- and the writting to the file if needed
!-
!- We test for the work to be done at this time here so that at a
!- later stage we can call different operation and write subroutine
!- for the REAL and INTEGER interfaces
!-
!- INPUT
!- idf      : The ID of the file on which this variable is to be,
!-            written. The variable should have been defined in
!-            this file before.
!- pvarname : The short name of the variable
!- pitau    : Current timestep
!- pdata    : The variable, I mean the real data !
!- nbindex  : The number of indexes provided. If it is equal to
!-            the size of the full field as provided in histdef
!-            then nothing is done.
!- nindex   : The indices used to expand the variable (pdata)
!-            onto the full field.
```

This is the qrp definition

```
   REAL(wp), PUBLIC, ALLOCATABLE, SAVE, DIMENSION(:,:) ::   qrp   !: heat flux damping        [w/m2]
```

I searched online and find some information saying this is due to a fortran 2003 standard about null pointer. And different compilers treat null pointer differently. As I know gfortran is mostly used for compiling this code and seemingly working fine. I would like to know what I can do to avoid the error without changing the compiler.

Comment: How is `qrp` defined? If it is `ALLOCATABLE` array, is it allocated? How is `histwrite` defined?

Comment: @jacob, I've added the interface definition of histwrite in the question and as well as the declare of qrp. It is an allocatable array and I think it is not allocated.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code, the interface `histwrite` resolves to the following subroutine for your `qrp`:

```
SUBROUTINE histwrite_r2d (idf,pvarname,pitau,pdata,nbindex,nindex)
!---------------------------------------------------------------------
  IMPLICIT NONE
!-
  INTEGER,INTENT(IN) :: idf,pitau,nbindex
  INTEGER,DIMENSION(nbindex),INTENT(IN) :: nindex
  REAL,DIMENSION(:,:),INTENT(IN) :: pdata
  CHARACTER(LEN=*),INTENT(IN) :: pvarname
!---------------------------------------------------------------------
  CALL histw_rnd (idf,pvarname,pitau,nbindex,nindex,pdata_2d=pdata)
!---------------------------
END SUBROUTINE histwrite_r2d
```

The dummy argument `pdata` (to be associated with the actual `qrp`) is a assumed-shape array, but not allocatable. This means that the paragraph 7 of section 15.5.2.4 of the [current Fortran standard](http://isotc.iso.org/livelink/livelink?func=ll&objId=19442438&objAction=Open) applies:

> 7. Except in references to intrinsic inquiry functions, if the dummy argument is nonoptional and the actual argument
>      is allocatable, the corresponding actual argument **shall be allocated**.

In other words, passing a non-allocated `qrp` to `histwrite` is invalid in Fortran, because the compiler can't associate non-existing array with an existing one.

I believe that, internally, gfortran just passes on a null pointer, which then makes the optional argument `pdata_2d` in call to `histw_rnd` appear as *not present*. But I suspect that this is more of a coindidence than a design.

There's little you can do; this is a problem of the code. You would need to fix it yourself, perhaps by using directly `histw_rnd` (bypassing `histwrite`) without any of its optional arguments, or by allocating `qrp`. I don't think there is a magical compiler option for PGI that would just solve it for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot @jacob. I'm not expert, only started the installation of the software and want to make use of it. Do you think additional IF statement to pass a null pointer when qrp is not allocated is feasible?

Comment: @user3289737 I can imagine making the dummy argument `pdata` allocatable in all subroutines `histwrite_r?d`, and adding an IF into those subroutines to only pass that array into the dummy argument `pdata_?d` of `histw_rnd` when allocated.